# What kind of Project is VSTO?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vsto

We are working with an Outlook Add-in using VSTO for desktop Outlook Version 2007,2010,2013 and 2016 version.

Please let me know if VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) itself is a type of project or does it falls in any other kind of project (example: Winforms or WPF) ? 
 
Most of the times when we face issues and try to search solutions over net, we have been asked what's the type of project?

Lately I have been searching for "how to slide a panel (sliding effect) ?" and when I started searching for it, I had stumbled over a lot of threads but most of the people were asking about the type of project and application, hope I justified myself asking this basic naïve question. Thanks

Note:

```
Under properties -> Application <br> 
Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.5.2 <br>
Output type: Class Library
```

It is not an output type: `Windows Application` nor a `Console Application`

Comment: Basically any AddIn is nothing but a library (DLL) that you can reference as any other and that is handled by VS in a special way. However this makes no difference on the project itself.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157876.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) is a set of development tools
> available in the form of a Visual Studio add-in (project templates)
> and a runtime that allows Microsoft Office 2003 and later versions of
> Office applications to host the .NET Framework Common Language Runtime
> (CLR) to expose their functionality via .NET.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office

Focusing on your question, the project is if you indeed look at the properties 'just' a Class Library. The only difference is that your class library is interfacing with Office and is able to interact with your class library because it implemented the interfaces that Office recognizes acting as a bridge between Office and .NET, this was even the 'logo' used by the VSTO team:

[image]

The project on itself can be anything you like and do whatever you want. If you can do it in .NET you can do it in a VSTO project, in C#, VB.NET whatever you like best. Office, in your project is just a referenced object model in order for you to talk against and have Office do/create nice documents, reports or presentations.

When your project is finished and deployed, Office will recognize this .NET Class Library and lights up the functionality that you built in your project.

Remember that although the project is a Class Library, you can use the full stack, WinForms, WPF, Console etc. etc. to extend Office with Ribbons, TaskPanes, Action Panes, Dialogs but also tasks without UI.